# ImportError: No module named neurolab

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, neural-network, neurolab

I try to import nuurolab using this code:

```
import neurolab as nl
```

But it gives this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neurolab'
```

Then I try to install neurolab using

```
sudo pip3 install neurolab
```

Then this message shows :

```
Requirement already satisfied: neurolab in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you running python in a virtual env or otherwise a version that *isn't* the python you've thought you've installed a library to?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Show us the output of `python --version`.

Comment: I used python version 3.6.3

Comment: that's a hint though surely? :p Look at what your path says...

Comment: You shouldn't use pip with sudo, prefer the --user option.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing the module in the wrong place.  By default on Linux there are 2 integrated versions, 2.7 and 3.5 plus the one you installed.  It is important not to confuse between them when installing modules or it will end up in the wrong version.

When typed in the terminal:

`python` brings up 2.7
`python3` brings up 3.5

and for python 3.6 it will be `python3.6`.

`pip` does this as well.

`pip` will be for 2.7
`pip3` for 3.5

and

`pip3.6` for 3.6

So when installing you just have to change which environment you install it in:

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install neurolab
```

If you get an error saying `pip3.6` cannot be found, in some cases it may be `pip36` otherwise you need to install `pip` for 3.6 using:

```
sudo apt install python3.6-pip
```

Comment: @GihanChathuranga How do you access your python 3.6 in terminal?

Comment: This error occurs when trying to install  python3.6-pip Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6-pip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6-pip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6-pip'

Comment: @GihanChathuranga  Did you try `sudo python3.6 -m pip install neurolab` first?  You may already have it.  Either way I need to know how you start python 3.6 in your terminal because that will be pretty much the same as pip.